# Returning data from within a Transaction in Laravel 4

Tags: php, closures, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code snippet which I can't seem to get it working.

```
$paymentGatewayTransaction = $this->processTransaction($data);
DB::connection('new_db')->transaction(function () use ($paymentGatewayTransaction) {
    //Performing all DB transactions here to insert Order Information.
    if ($paymentGatewayTransaction['Status'] == "APPROVED")
        return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Success'), '200'); else
        return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Error'), '200');
});

function processTransaction($data) {
    //Process Gateway Transaction
    if ($gatewayWasSuccessfull)
        return array('Status' => 'APPROVED'); else
        return array('Status' => 'DECLINED');
}
```

The return Response::json() on lines `5` and `7` don't seem to have any effect at all. The response never reaches the browser.

If I move the if condition from lines `4` thru `8` outside of the closure function, it works fine.

I had to end up doing the following as a workaround.

```
$paymentGatewayTransaction = $this->processTransaction($data);
$orderObj = "";
DB::connection('new_db')->transaction(function () use ($paymentGatewayTransaction, &$orderObj) {
    //Performing all DB transactions here to insert Order Information.
    // **$orderObj is set here**
});

if ($paymentGatewayTransaction['Status'] == "APPROVED")
    return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Success', 'Order' => $orderObj->id), '200'); else
    return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Error'), '200');

function processTransaction($data) {
    //Process Gateway Transaction
    if ($gatewayWasSuccessfull)
        return array('Status' => 'APPROVED'); else
        return array('Status' => 'DECLINED');
}
```

Created the object `$orderObj` outside of the Closure and made it as a variable by reference to the transaction to use it outside the closure function. Can this be any simpler or is this the way to go about using it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can assign the return values of the transaction closure in a variable like this:

```
$paymentGatewayTransaction = $this->processTransaction($data);
$var = DB::connection('new_db')->transaction(function () use ($paymentGatewayTransaction) {
    //Performing all DB transactions here to insert Order Information.
    if ($paymentGatewayTransaction['Status'] == "APPROVED")
        return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Success'), '200'); else
        return Response::json(array('Status' => 'Error'), '200');
});
return $var;
```

Then you can use $var to return.

Comment: This is very interesting since it means that any return statements from within `transaction()` stay in `transaction()` much like the function statement.